# MySQL "like" (false positive)

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database, with a field named "tags", e.g. iOS, Android, Java, JavaScript, etc.. And I want to select all the items in this table, who match some tag, e.g

> id | name  | tags
>
> -- | -------  | -----
>
> 1  | name1 | iOS,Android
>
> 2  | name2 | JavaScript,CSS
>
> 3  | name3 | HTML,Java

now, if I want only the items who have the tag 'Java' (only the one with id=3), i do this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags LIKE '%Java%';
```

but, as you imagine, it returns me the second (JavaScript) and the third (Java) items..

How can I do to only return the third?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags LIKE '%Java';`

Comment: Google for many-to-many relations

Comment: You should use relation table instead, and make your `LIKE` clause wisely

Comment: thanks for your answers! i'm not using relations because i'm using a database with MyISAM engine, and this engine does not support relations.. thanks again!

Comment: This is a bad data design. Try having a `tag` table with columns of, say, `tag_id` and `tag_name`, and then a separate lookup table with `id` (ie the ID from your table above) and `tag_id`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In MySQL, the best solution is `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE find_in_set('Java', tags) > 0;
```

In MySQL and other databases, you can also do this with `like`, but you need to put delimiters around everything:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE concat(',', tags, ',') like '%,Java,%';
```

The delimited prevent confusion with similar tags (well, confusion that doesn't involve commas).

Comment: I'm just wondering if what exactly the difference between `LIKE '%Java%';` and `concat(',', tags, ',') like '%,Java,%';`. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristianMark . . . The first will match `'Javascript'`.  The second will not.